# help finding this surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given that $$S : z = xe^y, \hspace{1mm} 0 \leq x\leq 1,  \hspace{1mm} 0 \leq y\leq 1 $$

Find $$\int\int_S \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)dS$$ upto four decimal places

Comment: Hi! Can you show any of your work on this so far or explain where you got into troubles with this integral? This way it is easier to help you!

Comment: I understand that $$dS = \sqrt{(dxdy)^2+(dydz)^2+(dxdz)^2} = \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{dz}{dy}\right)^2}\hspace{1mm}dxdy  $$

Comment: Which gives me $$ \int_0^1\int_0^1 (y^2+x^2(1+e^{2y}))\sqrt{1+(1+x^2)e^{2y}}\hspace{1mm}dxdy  $$

Comment: I have no Idea what to from here, we are asked to approximate upto 4 decimal places. Should we do numerical integration by dividing the region D : 0<x, y<1 into small pieces, but how will that gaurantee that the result is  correct within 4 decimal places